# Is it faster to inflate a single layout file with multiple "gone" views or multiple layouts in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a simple question and answer application that (in the future) will support showing in a single `RecyclerView` a big number of different questions.

Each question (for now) has a question and an answer part.

Each list item has a `TextView` for the question (along with some other decorative stuff) and then I have to add the answer part.

There are two ways I can go about. Add a `View` for each type of answer I can have (there are currently 12 type of answers, such as text, number, slider, date , date range etc) and on the `ViewHolder` of the `RecyclerView` set all non used views to "gone",  or create 12 different list item layouts (which will have the question parts aswell) and pass a different `viewType` in the `onCreateViewHolder` method which will create one of 12 different `ViewHolders` which will extend one abstract `ViewHolder` which will handle the common stuff.

So can anyone tell me which of the two methods is better? Also my concern is speed (it is projected that at some point this may reach up to one thousand list items) so speed-wise what would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious **creating different views type will be more efficient** and good practice. And will make your list smoother. (as you said, will have large number of items)

Reason being.

- View will only render required view. (As you have given type for items.) Thus will require less memory in UI thread.
- If you include all views in RecyclerView item, they all will render (even if invisible).
- Remember all stuff in layout has its class and methods. It is for sure better to render 2 classes than 10 classes.